# Quick Filesharing Web-App

Tags: looking-for-a-script, web-applications, http, ftp

I need to provide ftp/http services for a group of users such that:

- each user has his own password protected area where he can upload files
- each user can create user accounts and passwords for the files he wants to share

Anybody know of a simple, self-installed, web app that will accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Try DropBox (http://dropbox.com). This is not exactly what you have described but should be OK.

1. First, let each of your users create an account. This way they will get their individual spaces of at least 2GB.
2. Then, make them install DP's desktop application. This is not necessary but very helpful. All it does is synchronizing a designated folder with a user's online space.

It works like every regular folder. If you drag and drop a file into it, the app will start synchronizing it with the online space. If you rename it, move it or delete it - all the changes will be reflected online, too. It is just like a mix of instant online back-up and file sharing.

Now, if your users want to share some files, they can just sort them in folders in their DropBox folder and designate users with access to each folder separately. What is best about it, is that if user A allows user B access to a folder, this folder is being automatically synchronized with both users' desktops, which means that everybody is up to date with their files.

It works very well and at the same time is free and simple. The functionality is very limited in terms of available options but the implementation is flexible enough so that it is easy to have a setup that is fit for various tasks.

Comment: I looked at Dropbox - appears to be a commercial project that stores user's data on their cloudspace. I'm looking for something to install on our own servers. Something like an ftp server with a web interface that allows users grant access for others to their own accounts.

Comment: Oh, I have no idea then, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

[Mollify](http://www.mollify.org/) should get you most of the way there. The main thing I'm not sure of is having each of your people be able to manage their own sub-group of people. You might be able to mimic it with the groups feature instead. Or just separate installs if it's not too big a group of people, I suppose.
(Having multiple, independent, admins under one system like that is a *lot* of user/permissions management and starts pushing the boundaries of you asking for "simple." I'm not sure it's even such a great idea, to be honest.)